# Timing ASP.NET Page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to measure the code run time in ASP.NET page?

Here is my code, trying to time the page load and writing to log.

```
   private Stopwatch PageTimer = null;

    protected void Page_Init(Object Src, EventArgs E)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PageTimer = new Stopwatch();
            PageTimer.Start();


        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PageTimer.Stop();
            Logger.SectionEnd("PageTimer", PageTimer, "", true);
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you use a HttpModule for that. There's one you can use at

[HttpModule For Timing Requests](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/02/httpmodule-for-timing-requests.aspx)
(pretty old, I know, but still valid)

A good thing about HttpModules is that you have them self-register themselves if the "main application" has code for it. Using a module in another application is then just a copy paste in to the bin folder and it will start to operate.

If the "main application" doesn't support modules to self-register it can be added to the bin and web.config to start operating.

Answer (score 4):

You may try [mvc-mini-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/).

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like something simple and fast i suggest using the global.asax file.
You can create this file by selecting new file in a website.

The global.asax file has a few methods, the ones you should be looking for are 
Application_BeginRequest
Application_EndRequest

You could start a timer, write some logging , do whatever to get the time between these 2 requests.
By doing it like this you have the exact time the request spent on your server, if you do it in the page_load and page_prerender you miss out on stuff like redirection, authentication, membership etc

Comment: The timer can be stored in Context.Items. I did that with a Stopwatch and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another choice: [Web Performance Test Using Visual Studio](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article901-web-performance-test-using-visual-studio-part-i-.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude logging, you can use firebug to measure client-side performance.